# unable to post status to facebook

Tags: facebook

```
require_once 'facebook.php';  

$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, $appsecret);  

if($facebook->api_client->users_hasAppPermission("status_update"))
    $facebook->api_client->users_setStatus("Hi there");
```

I am unable to post status to facebook, the above says nothing :(

I already gave status update permission to my app. help please..

Answer (score 0):

Current functionu is "Users_hasAppPermission"

"U" must be capital in both  functions